# How keep session active when user clicks checkbox compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I have been trying to implement a checked box where is user says keep me signed in they stay signed in. The problem however is I am wondering how can I store this value in the pref and and if its positive they just log in.

in my viewModel I have this function

```
 fun keepSignedIn(updatedValue: Boolean){
     keepSignedIn.value = updatedValue
 }
```

and in my content screen

```
@Composable
fun KeepMeSignedInCheckBox() {
  
    Checkbox(checked = state.keepMeSignedIn, onCheckedChange = keepMeSignedIn.invoke(it))
}
```

I am wondering what is the best way to update this value in the `view Model`? I have my login function in the view model too.

What I have tried,

```
fun keepSignedIn(updatedValue: Boolean){
    keepSignedIn.value = updatedValue
    val signedIn = instance().keepUserSignedIn
    if(signedIn){
        loginUser
    }
}
```

But my approach does not work when I leave the app it take me to login screen, and does not store that session.

Comment: Where are the `SharedPref`s?

Answer (score 0):

Initialize the variable as

```
val sessionStored by mutableStateOf(
                        context.getSharedPreferences("prefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
                               .getBoolean("isSessionStored", false)
                     )
```

Where `"prefs"` is the name you assigned to the preferences, `MODE_PRIVATE` is the mode of accessing the `SharedPreferences`, `"isSessionStored"` the name of the preference field and `false` its default value, for obvious reasons.

Use it like so

```
Checkbox(checked = state.sessionStored, onCheckedChange = viewModel::setSessionStored)
```

Define `setSessionStored` like so

```
fun setSessionStored(sessionStored: Boolean) {
  this.sessionStored = sessionStored
  context.getSharedPreferences("prefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
         .edit()
         .putBoolean("isSessionStored", sessionStored)
         .apply()
}
```

'll Work like a charm,

Here's a piece to code to https://youtu.be/RsEoX0FbETI

Comment: Can you add a context in the view model?

Comment: Of course, but if you do not want to go there, just add an extra parameter in the update function to receive a context object from the caller. Move the initialization logic to a separate function as well, then call that from an activity as well with a context object.